# Create association based on array column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 tables 
`Store` and `StoreItem`

`StoreItem` has column names `store_ids` which is array [1,2,3]

`store has_many :store_items`

`store_item belongs_to :store`

how to connect them properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to model a n-to-m relation (a store has multiple items and an item can appear in different stores) you should use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, where you have to create a join table, in this case `stores_store_items`.

See the official docs: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many